# Как прокинуть Id записи в другое поле при создании?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Использую `CodeFirst` `EntityFramework`

У меня есть класс

```
public class MenuItem 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortNumber { get;set; }
}
```

Мне надо что бы при его создании в `SortNumber` попал `Id`.

Как я это сейчас делаю

```
MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
menuItem.Title = "Hallow";
db.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
db.SaveChanges();

menuItem.SortNumer = menuItem.Id;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Этот код работает, но он уже не атомарен, и при сбое на сервере есть риск что элемент создастся, но `SortNumber` так и не будет присвоен правильно.

Как я это решаю на данный момент, создаю транзакцию поверх этих операций, для достижения целостности базы данных и атомарности операции.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead }))
{
    MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
    menuItem.Title = "Hallow";
    db.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
    db.SaveChanges();
    menuItem.SortNumer = menuItem.Id;
    db.SaveChanges();

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Есть ли какие-то другие альтернативные варианты, возможно как-то проще сделать? Как это правильно делать?

В данном случае надо просто `SortNumber` сделать равным `Id`, но это пример, иногда надо какую-то строчку сформировать на основе `Id` и записать в этот же класс, надо что бы ответ подходил и для этих вариантов.

Код приведённый выше написан для `EntityFramework 6` без `Core` но меня интересует решение для `Core` версии.

Comment: то есть вам нужно вычисляемое на основе Id поле?

Comment: @tym32167 оно вычисляемое только при создании, потом туда нужно будет записывать другие значения, то есть жёсткой привязки быть не должно

Comment: то есть вам надо что то типа триггера на insert в БД, только в виде конструкции в EF?

Comment: @tym32167  это один из способов задания объекта, есть и другие способы, то есть тригер который срабатывает всегда не подходит

Comment: @tym32167 пример: я для тестовой базы заполняю на форуме сообщения в инициализаторе и в текст сообщения вставляю Id для простоты отладки. Но в продакшене такого не будет, и там сообщение задаётся из POST запроса.

Comment: Интересно бы узнать ответ на это. Нагуглилось только [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800215/ef-code-first-how-to-insert-primary-key-to-another-field-when-inserting)

Comment: @tym32167 судя по тому ответу я делаю всё правильно. Жаль просто что приходится для такой простой задачи столько кода генерить.

Answer (score 0):

Я предложил бы использовать фабричный метод. И да, сделать его транзакцией.